# Newbie working on Horse Racing Database using R

Tags: r, database, for-loop

I'm new to the group and to R language.
I've written some code (below) that achieves the desired result.
However, i'm aware that i'm reproducing lines of the same code which would surely be more efficiently coded using a for loop.
Also, there will be races with large numbers of horses so I really need to be able to run a for loop that runs through each horse.
ie. num_runners = NROW(my_new_data)

my_new_data holds data on horses previous races.
DaH is a numeric rating that is attached to each of a horse's previous runs with DaH1 being the most recent and DaH6 is six races back.
Code, a character, signifies the type of race that the horse competed in. ie. Flat, Fences.

I have played with using for loops, ie. for(i in 1:6) without success.
Since I am assigning to a new horse each time I would hope something such as the following would work:

```
horse(i) = c(my_new_data$DaH1[i],my_new_data$DaH2[i],my_new_data$DaH3[i],my_new_data$DaH4[i],my_new_data$DaH5[i],my_new_data$DaH6[i])
But I know that horse(i) is not allowed.
Would my best strategy be to pre-define a dataframe of size: 6 rows and 6 columns
```

and use 2 for loops to populate [row][column]? Something like:

```
final_data[i,j]
```

Here is the code I am presently using which creates the dataframe racetest:

```
horse1 = c(my_new_data$DaH1[1],my_new_data$DaH2[1],my_new_data$DaH3[1],my_new_data$DaH4[1],my_new_data$DaH5[1],my_new_data$DaH6[1])
horse2 = c(my_new_data$DaH1[2],my_new_data$DaH2[2],my_new_data$DaH3[2],my_new_data$DaH4[2],my_new_data$DaH5[2],my_new_data$DaH6[2])
horse3 = c(my_new_data$DaH1[3],my_new_data$DaH2[3],my_new_data$DaH3[3],my_new_data$DaH4[3],my_new_data$DaH5[3],my_new_data$DaH6[3])
horse4 = c(my_new_data$DaH1[4],my_new_data$DaH2[4],my_new_data$DaH3[4],my_new_data$DaH4[4],my_new_data$DaH5[4],my_new_data$DaH6[4])
horse5 = c(my_new_data$DaH1[5],my_new_data$DaH2[5],my_new_data$DaH3[5],my_new_data$DaH4[5],my_new_data$DaH5[5],my_new_data$DaH6[5])
horse6 = c(my_new_data$DaH1[6],my_new_data$DaH2[6],my_new_data$DaH3[6],my_new_data$DaH4[6],my_new_data$DaH5[6],my_new_data$DaH6[6])
horse1.code = c(my_new_data$Code1[1],my_new_data$Code2[1],my_new_data$Code3[1],my_new_data$Code4[1],my_new_data$Code5[1],my_new_data$Code6[1])
horse2.code = c(my_new_data$Code1[2],my_new_data$Code2[2],my_new_data$Code3[2],my_new_data$Code4[2],my_new_data$Code5[2],my_new_data$Code6[2])
horse3.code = c(my_new_data$Code1[3],my_new_data$Code2[3],my_new_data$Code3[3],my_new_data$Code4[3],my_new_data$Code5[3],my_new_data$Code6[3])
horse4.code = c(my_new_data$Code1[4],my_new_data$Code2[4],my_new_data$Code3[4],my_new_data$Code4[4],my_new_data$Code5[4],my_new_data$Code6[4])
horse5.code = c(my_new_data$Code1[5],my_new_data$Code2[5],my_new_data$Code3[5],my_new_data$Code4[5],my_new_data$Code5[5],my_new_data$Code6[5])
horse6.code = c(my_new_data$Code1[6],my_new_data$Code2[6],my_new_data$Code3[6],my_new_data$Code4[6],my_new_data$Code5[6],my_new_data$Code6[6])

racetest = data.frame(horse1,horse1.code,horse2,horse2.code, horse3, horse3.code,
                      horse4,horse4.code,horse5,horse5.code, horse6, horse6.code)
```

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered!
Graham

Answer (score 0):

using loops in R is usually not the correct approach. Still I will give you something which might work.

There are two possible approaches I see here, I will address the simpler one:

if columns are ordered such that column 1:6 are named `DaH1` to `DaH6` and columns 7: 12 are the ones named `horse1.code` etc... in this case:

```
library(magrittr)

temp<- cbind(my_new_data[,1:6] %>% t,
             my_new_data[,7:12]%>% t)

Odd = seq(1,12,2)

my_new_data[ , Odd] = temp[,1:6]
my new_data[ , -Odd] = temp[,7:12]

#cleanup
rm(temp,Odd)
```

`my_new_data` should now contain your desired output. Before you run this, make sure your data is backed up inside another object as this is untested code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we want to `reshape` the wide format of the data in a different wide format. But first let's look at your desired `for` loop approach, to understand what's going on.

### Using a loop

For the loop we'll need two variables with sequences `i` and `j`.

```
## initialize matrix with dimnames
racetest <- matrix(NA, 3, 6, 
                   dimnames=list(c("DaH1", "DaH2", "DaH3"), 
                                 c("horse1", "horse1.code", "horse2", "horse2.code", 
                                   "horse3", "horse3.code")))

## loop
for (i in 0:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    racetest[j, 1:2+2*i] <- unlist(my_new_data[i+1, c(1, 4)])
  }
}
#      horse1 horse1.code horse2 horse2.code horse3 horse3.code
# DaH1      1           1      2           2      3           3
# DaH2      1           1      2           2      3           3
# DaH3      1           1      2           2      3           3
```

Often `for` loops are discouraged in R, because they might be slow and doesn't use the [vectorized features of the R language](http://alyssafrazee.com/2014/01/29/vectorization.html). Moreover they can also be tricky to program.

### Transposing column sets

We also could do a different approach. Actually we want to `t`ranspose the `DaH*` and `Code*` column sets (identifiable using `grep`) and bring them in the appropriate `order` using `substring` of `names`, with `nchar` as first character.

```
rownames(my_new_data) <- paste0("horse.", seq(nrow(my_new_data)))
rr <- data.frame(DaH=t(my_new_data[, grep("DaH", names(my_new_data))]), 
                 Code=t(my_new_data[, grep("Code", names(my_new_data))]))
rr <- rr[order(substring(names(rr), nchar(names(rr))))]
rr
#      DaH.horse.1 Code.horse.1 DaH.horse.2 Code.horse.2 DaH.horse.3 Code.horse.3
# DaH1           1            1           2            2           3            3
# DaH2           1            1           2            2           3            3
# DaH3           1            1           2            2           3            3
```

### Reshaping data

Last but not least, we actually want to `reshape` the data. For this we give the data set an ID variable.

```
my_new_data <- transform(my_new_data, horse=1:nrow(my_new_data))
```

At first, we `reshape` the data into `"long"` format, using the new ID variable `horse` and put the two `varying` column sets into a list.

```
rr1 <- reshape(my_new_data, idvar="horse", varying=list(1:3, 4:6), direction="long", sep="",
               v.names=c("DaH", "Code"))
rr1
#     horse time DaH Code
# 1.1     1    1   1    1
# 2.1     2    1   2    2
# 3.1     3    1   3    3
# 1.2     1    2   1    1
# 2.2     2    2   2    2
# 3.2     3    2   3    3
# 1.3     1    3   1    1
# 2.3     2    3   2    2
# 3.3     3    3   3    3
```

Then, in order to get the desired wide format, what we want is to swap `idvar` and `timevar`, where our new `idvar` is `"time"` and our new `timevar` is `"horse"`.

```
reshape(rr1, timevar="horse", idvar="time", direction= "wide")
#     time DaH.1 Code.1 DaH.2 Code.2 DaH.3 Code.3
# 1.1    1     1      1     2      2     3      3
# 1.2    2     1      1     2      2     3      3
# 1.3    3     1      1     2      2     3      3
```

### Benchmark

The benchmark reveals that of these three approaches `t`ransposing of the matrices is fastest, while the 'for' loop is actually by far the slowest.

```
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
#    forloop 7191.038 7373.5890 8381.8036 7576.678 7980.4320 46677.324   100   c
#  transpose  620.748  656.0845  707.7248  692.953  733.1365   944.773   100 a  
#    reshape 2791.710 2858.6830 3013.8372 2958.825 3118.4125  3871.960   100  b
```

---

*Toy data:*

```
my_new_data <- data.frame(DaH1=1:3, DaH2=1:3, DaH3=1:3, Code1=1:3, Code2=1:3, Code3=1:3)
```